# Laravel form display value

Tags: forms, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm trying to use its Form method. My form is working fine but there is 2 input field which can contain data from a previous form in the database.

What I want to do is to show these previously set data in these fields as default but the user can overwrite them if he/she wants.

I searched a lot and I may use the Form Model Binding but whatever I try it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me, please? Or maybe offer an other method?

Here is my Form as it is now:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => '','id' => 'formDummy','files' => true))}}
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td>{{Form::date('exgateDate', \Carbon\Carbon::now())}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Car:</td>
            <td>{{Form::select('car',$car->pluck('name','id'),null,['placeholder' => '','id' => 'car', 'class' => 'ddl'])}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number:</td>
            <td>{{Form::text('Number','',array('id' => 'Number', 'class' => 'txt'))}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Files:</td>
            <td>{{Form::file('dummyFile',array('multiple'=>true,'id' => 'dummyFiles'))}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">{{Form::button('Submit',array('id' => 'sendDummy'))}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: You need to pass the values from your controller to the blade. You can then easily do `$yourObject->value ? $yourObject->value : ''` as the value of the field

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper method `old` to retrieve inputs from a previous route (i.e., a redirect back happens due to a failed validation)

```
{{ old("input_name", "default_value") }}
```